# Unable to import URL class in Nodejs Typescript app

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am trying to import the URL class from the nodejs api so I can parse urls and retrieve their origin, hostname, and paths.

I am trying to do it by typing

`import * as URL from "url";`

and I have also tried

`import { URL } from "url";`

and I cannot seem to get this to work for me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The way I am trying to use this is as such

`var site = new URL("http://www.website.com");`

And it is throwing an error because it states that URL is not a constructor

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The [URL constructor](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_class_url) was introduced as part of node v7.0. `import { URL } from "url";` is the proper way to import it if you are using node >= v7.0. Make sure you are using the latest version of node typings as updated as well:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/node
```

If your node version is < 7.0 then you can use the `parse` method:

```
import * as url from "url";

var site = url.parse("http://www.website.com");
```

Comment: If you're targeting Node.js do not use that import syntax. Use `import m = require("m");`

Comment: @AluanHaddad Any reasons?

Comment: Yes many. One very important reason is https://github.com/nodejs/node-eps/blob/master/002-es-modules.md#46-es-consuming-commonjs

Comment: Thanks a lot dude, it was totally a version error, I had googled url parsers and was directed to the newest docs which caused the confusion, unfortunately the 6.x.x node url module does not contain an origin property but I can easily concat the protocol with the hostname

Comment: Also @AluanHaddad thanks for the link about importing modules, I have been using typescript for my quick node scripts and it's good to know why I should keep it to node standards

Comment: @AluanHaddad so what syntax do you suggest when importing only certain variables/functions from a module? For instance, in Node I was doing `const {URL} = require('url');`, so what should I use instead in TypeScript? Since the example you've shown doesn't work for this case, only when importing a full module.

Comment: @DávidPásztor you cannot.

Comment: @AluanHaddad the code in the answer, namely `import { URL } from "url";` actually works, I just wanted to know if there's a better option, but in this case I suppose there isn't one

Comment: `resolve` is a deprecated API, docs suggest using the WHATWG API, but what is the equivalent code there?

Answer (score 3):

```
import * as url from 'Url';

{ parse: [Function: urlParse],
  resolve: [Function: urlResolve],
  resolveObject: [Function: urlResolveObject],
  format: [Function: urlFormat],
  Url: [Function: Url] 
}
```

It's not a constructor.  You'll need to do use one of the exposed methods:

```
import * as url from 'url';

console.log(url.parse('https://www.google.com'))

// Output:
Url {
  protocol: 'https:',
  slashes: true,
  auth: null,
  host: 'www.google.com',
  port: null,
  hostname: 'www.google.com',
  hash: null,
  search: null,
  query: null,
  pathname: '/',
  path: '/',
  href: 'https://www.google.com/' }
undefined
>
```

Comment: If you're targeting Node.js do not use that import syntax. Use `import m = require("m");`

Answer (score 3):

If someone is wondering how to use `URL` so code is portable between Node.js and browser environment, then i've came to this solution:

```
import * as nodeUrl from "url";

const URL = typeof window !== "undefined" ? window.URL : nodeUrl.URL;
```

Comment: had to add `declare var window;` for it to work as answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/61871419/1997873