# typeof window == "undefined" throws an error while using ts-node

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typeof, ts-node

I have some code within which I'm using `typeof window == "undefined"` to check whether there is a browser environement. When I'm launching this code with `ts-node`, I'm getting this:

```
typings/Console.ts:36:10 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'window'.

36      typeof window == "undefined"
               ~~~~~~
```

AFAIK `typeof` is kind of operator that is safe to use with not defined variables, and it works well both  in browser and in NodeJS environement. But as far as I start to use it with `ts-node`, it starts to throw.

My `tsconfig.json`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "CommonJS",
        "target": "es5",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "baseUrl": "src",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "strict": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "traceResolution": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,

        "allowJs": false,
        "declaration": false,
        "removeComments": true,
        "noLib": false,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
        "types": [ "node" ],
        "lib": [ "es6" ],
        "downlevelIteration": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "typeRoots": [
            "../node_modules/@types"
        ]
    }
}
```

So, what the trick?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: you could try typeof (window || undefined) == "undefined"

Comment: try add to lib in tsconfig "DOM"

Comment: @LukaKostic This won't help because `window` is still not defined.

Comment: @kalit well, don't understand why, but it helped. Seems more like a bug than like an expected behavior. Thank you! Post your comment as answer to allow me to mark it as right answer :)

Comment: @Limbo but there is only check type is defined, not object, maybe somewhere later is defined

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try add to lib in tsconfig "DOM"

Answer (score 3):

For me it worked to first declare the variable to TypeScript, so:

```
declare var window;

if(typeof window == "undefined"){
// code
}
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, this approach is not good when your project is basically browser oriented and you have several similar conditions across the sources (e.g. `typeof document != "undefined"`, `typeof navigator != "undefined`, etc.). As answered by @kalit the problem could be solved by adding `"DOM"` to `"lib"` property of `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: Generally speaking, the `typeof` operator in Typescript is useless because it does not allow you to be used with totally not defined variables, that goes in contrast with vanilla JS `typeof` operator.